# Passing value from LoginComponent to RootComponent

Tags: angular, typescript

I am struggling on using *ngIf for removing the login / logout in the navbar. If I logged in, the logout link should be hidden. Please see my setup.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { UserService } from './user';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app works!';

  loginstatus: boolean = false;

  constructor(private _userService: UserService, private _router: Router){}

  onLogout(){
    this._userService.logout();
    this._router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.onLogout();
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<ul class="navigation">
  <li *ngIf="!loginstatus"><a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a></li>
  <li *ngIf="loginstatus"><a (click)="onLogout()">Logout</a></li>
</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
    user = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    }

    loginForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _userService: UserService, private _formBuilder: FormBuilder){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.loginForm = this._formBuilder.group({
            username: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    onLogin(){
        this._userService.postUserLogin(this.user)
            .subscribe(token => {
                console.log(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
            })
            err => console.log(err);
    }
}
```

As we can see, I am using the variable *loginstatus* to determine if the user is logged in or not. Now my question is, from login component, how can I change the value of *loginstatus* in order to hide the login from the navbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that you don't really want a `value` to be shared; you want the event when it is changed. The event could be a real event implemented with e.g. `EventEmitter` or `rxjs` or a standard angular change detection with `ngOnChanges`.

E.g. create RX subject:

```
export const loginStatusChanged = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

which means by default user is not logged in.

Then in the app.component subscribe to the event:

```
import { loginStatusChanged } from ...;

...

loginStatus: boolean;

...

ngOnInit() {
  loginStatusChanged.subscribe(status => this.loginStatus = status);
}
```

and in login.component

```
...
// when logged in
loginStatusChanged.next(true);
...
```

One may argue here that it is better to do this with a service. Maybe. Maybe not. I think in this particular case it does not really matter. It works, it is still easy to unit-test even without injection.

A small reminder: if it was not the AppComponent it would make sense to `unsubscribe` from observable or use [ng2-rx-collector](https://github.com/smnbbrv/ng2-rx-collector) (sorry, ads :D). Here it is not really necessary because AppComponent is destroyed only when you shut down the whole app.

Comment: can I ask what package of rx should I import when using BehaviorSubject without importing the whole rx if possible?

Comment: nevermind I already got it. Its 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to create common service which shared between your `LoginComponent` and `AppComponent` and with this service you can communicate between `LoginComponent` and `AppComponent`. Check [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) documentation.